# why is my navbar does not work when i have certain bootstrap cdn on it

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have created a navbar file that i include in everypage using php, however the pages tha has certain bootstrap cdn  makes the dropdown menu stop working, i spent days doing process of elimination to find out that the issue is on the cdn, is there something i am missing here that i should know about cdns links? Pease help:
here is mine navbar file that i include in every page using php. and also the file in which I that has the cdn

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #83c5be;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #006d77;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.index {
  background-color: #edf6f9;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #e29578;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style
</head>
<body>



<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home btn" class="navbar-button active">Admin</a>
 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">User Apps
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="btn" href="/reminders/index.php">Reminder</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/wallet/cards/new-card.php">Wallet</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/budget/index.php">Budget</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/register/index.php">Shopping Calculator</a>

    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Admin Apps
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="btn" href="/snippets/index.php">Snippets</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/notebook/notebook.php">Code Notebook</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/site-users-manager/">Site Users Admin</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/tiny-files-manager/index.php">System File Editor</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/ftpweb/">Web FTP</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Database
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="btn" href="webme.mywire.org/phpmyadmin">WAN</a>
      <a class="btn" href="http://localhost/phpmyadmin">LOCAL</a>
      <a class="btn" href="http://10.0.0.235/phpmyadmin/">LAN</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Webme Folders
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="btn" href="/workspace/">Workspace</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/navbars/">Navbars</a>
      <a class="btn" href="/logos/">Logos</a>
<a class="btn" href="/homepage/">Homepage</a>
<a class="btn" href="/users/">Users</a>
<a class="btn" href="/code-builder/">MySQL Code Builde</a>
<a class="btn" href="/register/">Cash Register</a>
<a class="btn" href="/material-components-web-codelabs-master/">codelabs M. Design css</a>



      <a class="btn" href="/webme-user-folder/">WEBme Users Folder</a>
     

   
    </div>
  </div> 
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Image Utilities
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="btn" href="/png2ico/">png2ico</a>
     
     

   
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a class="btn"
  class="navbar-button user" href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunctionNavbar()">&#9776;</a>
  <div  style="float:right" class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> &nbsp; User 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content navbar-button">
      <a class="btn" href="/logout.php"> <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i> &nbsp;log out</a>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<script>
function myFunctionNavbar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is part of the code file that has the cdn in it

```
<html lang="en" >
  
<head>
  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Webme - Shopping <i class="fa fa-calculator" aria-hidden="true"></i></title>
  <html ng-app="">
 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd2c0fb4b5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
   

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

       .not4mobile{
            display: none;
        }

}

body{
  margin-top:20px;
background-color: #0096c7;
font-size: 20px;
}

.invoice {
    padding: 30px;
}

.invoice h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

.invoice .small {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.invoice hr {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-color: #ddd;
}

.invoice .table tr.line {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.invoice .table td {
    border: none;
}

.invoice .identity {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.invoice .identity strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}


.grid {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    color: #666666;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #90e0ef;
  color: black;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #48cae4
;
  color: black;
}

.header {
  color: #03045e;

}
.panel-body{
  background-color: #caf0f8;

}
.toright{
  float: right;
}
</style>




</head>
<body>
<?php 

if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
include_once '../navbars/webmenav/navbar-login.php';
}else {
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
      if ($userid== "marcos60649"){
    include '../navbars/webmenav/navbar-admin.php';
    } else {
    include '../navbars/webmenav/navbar-user.php';
    }
  }
 ?>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller=itemsController>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <p class="panel-title total-amount text-center header">Shopping Calculator</span></p>
          <p class="panel-title item-display"></span></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form name="cashRegister" action="add.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <!-- Product Selector -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4 product-inputs-left ui-widget">
                <input class="form-control input-lg" list="product_names" type="text" ng-model="inputed_product_name" ng-change="select_product()" name="name">
                  <datalist id="product_names">
                    <option ng-repeat="a in product_list" value="{{a.name}}">
                  </datalist>
                <span class="help-block help-block-label">Type item</span>
              </div>
              
              <div class="col-md-3 product-inputs">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-addon" id="currencySymbol">$</div>
                  <input ng-model="product_cost" name="price" inputmode="decimal" id="productUnitCost" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" >
                </div>
                <span class="help-block help-block-label">Unit Cost</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2 product-inputs">
                <input class="form-control input-lg" inputmode="numeric" type="number" ng-model="inputed_product_quantity" name="qty" ng-change="select_quantity()">
                <span class="help-block help-block-label">Choose Quantity</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 product-inputs-right">
                <button id="btnsettings" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="btnAddProduct" ng-click=add_to_cart()>ADD</button>
                <span class="help-block help-block-label">Add to Cart</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
           <!-- Cart contents -->

<table class="table ">
                                            <thead class="cols-12">
<tr>                                        
                                            
                                            <th class="cols-1 cols-sm-1" >
</strong>#</th>
                                                    <th class="text-left cols-9 cols-sm-8"><strong>ITEM</strong></th>
                                                    <th class="text-right cols-1 cols-sm-1"><strong>QTY</strong></th>
                                                    <th class="text-right cols-1 cols-sm-1"><strong>PRICE</strong></th>
                                                        <th class="text-right cols-1 cols-sm-1 not4mobile"><strong>SUBTOTAL</strong></th>

                                            
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="display">

           
                        

</div>
```

i tried putting the cdn inside of the navbar file, i tried all kind of version of cdn and nothing works

Comment: Which CDN are you referring to? And perhaps more significantly, why are you referencing 2 different versions of Bootstrap CSS in the same page?? That by itself seems like a recipe for trouble. Do you fully understand what these links refer to?

Comment: ALso your navbar page contains a big mistake...you cannot have `<doctype`, `<html>`, `<head` and `<body` tags inside another HTML document. You must only send one single HTML document to the browser to form a page. If you are putting the navbar code inside other pages, it must _not_ contain its own HTML document tags. It's not valid, and it also does not make any logical sense.

Comment: Lastly...if you're planning to use bootstrap, it comes with a whole set of tools for making a navbar. Why don't you use that, to make your life easier, and avoid potential conflicts between your CSS and the bootstrap CSS? I would also recommend to use the latest bootstrap 5.2 release. Currently your page references 5.0.2 **and** 3.3.2, as I mentioned above. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/

Comment: i just found out that the navbar works perfectly fine  with the bootstraps cdn on mobile devices, is just when i view on desktop that the dropdown menus dont work, and i removed the <html> tag from the navbar file but still doesnt work when page viewed from my laptop , and i also tried navbar created with bootstrap and they all work fine on mobile devices but not on desktop the dropdown doesnt work

Comment: Bootstrap navbar and dropdown works perfectly fine on all screen sizes, you can see that on the demos in the documentation page. Maybe you implemented it wrong. Start with the demo code and go from there. Have you removed the CSS for bootstrap 3 from your page yet?